# Keras will work with one approach to tokenize words, but not another

Tags: python, keras, artificial-intelligence

I have a dataframe with the following data:

```
        gender  gender_count    name    vectorized                    indexised ends_a
18948   1       308             macel   [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  [12, 0, 2, 4, 11, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan] 0
```

I use two approaches to tokenize words:

#### number of letters in `a-z` dictionary:

```py
char_dict = [(key,value) for key, value in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase)]
def vectorize(text, dictionary=char_dict): 
    vector = np.zeros(len(dictionary)) 
    for i, word in dictionary: 
        num = 0 
        for w in text: 
            if w == word: 
                num += 1 
        if num: 
            vector[i] = num 
    return vector
```

#### index of letter position in `a-z` dictionary:

```py
def indexise(name):
    #longest word len: 15
    name = name.lower()
    word = [string.ascii_lowercase.index(x) for x in name]
    for x in range(15-len(word)):
        word.append(np.nan)
    return word
```

As suggested by @hobbs below, if I change the empty letters in this approach from `np.nan` to say `-2`, the output is not zero, but very close to zero whist first approach with the same model generates 0.72 accuracy (20x better):

```
Log-loss (cost function):
training   (min:    5.469, max:    5.777, cur:    5.470)
validation (min:    7.109, max:    7.452, cur:    7.445)

Accuracy:
training   (min:    0.023, max:    0.119, cur:    0.025)
validation (min:    0.027, max:    0.137, cur:    0.031)
```

I use the same model in both approaches, the only things that's different is the `input_dim`.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=26, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X1, Y1, epochs=50, batch_size=1000, validation_split=.2, callbacks=[PlotLossesKeras()], verbose=False)
```

What I don't understand is why the first approach "works" - the model will train and validate and the second approach is always zero for validation/training and loss?

What makes such a big difference?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that having NaNs in the input makes the entire output useless.

Comment: well, if I change the NaN to -2, the output is technically not zero, by practically is :) Updated the post.